# When checking for transposed day and month values between two Dates - should comparing 11/11/2000 and 11/11/2000 return true or false?

Tags: algorithms, api, language-agnostic

Assuming a function with a signature of

```
boolean isTransposed(Date date1, Date date2);
```

Example outcomes:

```
date1   date2           Outcome
06/02/2000  02/06/2000  true
02/06/2000  06/02/2000  true
02/06/2000        null  false
06/02/2000  02/06/1987  false
11/11/2000  11/11/2000  true
04/04/2001  04/04/2000  false
```

Granted the behavior can be documented but what are your thoughts on `isTransposed('11/11/2000', '11/11/2000')` returning `true` verse `false`?

Comment: Code Review is for reviewing code, but this isn't code. As for your actual question: what is the purpose of the function? i.e. why do you care if two dates are transposed?

Comment: So we can't get a code review on an interface definition?

Comment: I don't think asking a specific question about the correct output for a specific function qualifies as a code review.

Answer (score 7):

A boolean is not a sufficient return value to return the comparison. If you are writing generic code, you want something thats tri state. Probable an enum like

```
enum TransposeResult
{
   notTransposed,
   transposed,
   inputIdentical,
};

TransposeResult calcTransposeState(...)
```

Then leave it up to the user to figure out what to do when they're already identical.

Comment: I understand your point in terms of absolute correctness.  But I would feel compelled to lose the 'is' in the method name and call it something calcTransposeState(date1, date2). Thoughts on an alternate method name?  Any isXYZ method that did not return true or false would be bad design in my opinion - sort of like isEmpty(null) returns true.

Comment: @Brian Good point, I agree. Updated.

Answer (score 5):

You ask what the code should do, I ask back what does the customer want it to do.

Any other answer is a bad answer even it is correct, as at best it's a guess, not requirements based.

Requirements is where significant numbers of software projects fail, and this is a clear example of a requirements problem. It's insignificant and won't derail your project on it's own, just one more one hole in the proverbial Swiss Cheese. Put away you compiler and get out you requirements management tool and resolve the requirements problem.

Comment: +1 Indeed, the question would have been infinitely better asked if it included a definition of what the expected behavior is, rather than asking us to infer it from the name.

Comment: @RossPatterson: So, aside from posting the actual result and the obvious *"Granted the behavior can be documented but what are your thoughts on [method] returning [actual result] verse [some other result]?"*, what exactly is missing from that question? I understand that the *expected behavior* is *specifically what OP* is inquiring about. As far as this answer goes, it's totally missing the point IMO, although I wish I could say otherwise.

Comment: @netcoder: Your answer, which addresses the question of which of several possible interpretations of "transposed", is a great example of why mattnz's answer is important.  You directly address the question of requirements in stating two possible intentions, but you had to reverse-engineer them from Brian's stated outputs and function name.

Comment: @RossPatterson: My answer addresses the difference between `is` and `hasBeen`, which are semantically different, not different interpretations of *"transposed"*. There was not reverse-engineering involved, it was actually quite the opposite.

Comment: The fact this conversation is occurring is why the code should be parked and the actual requirement determined. If you cannot be certain that you are implement what is required, how can you be certain that you are implementing the correct solution.

Comment: @mattnz: This just seems to me like a generic answer you could post to a lot of questions both on SO and SE, and probably be right 50% of the time, if not more. I can't say it's not true, just that I don't find it particularly useful.

Comment: @netcoder, it is more useful than your answer because this is a case when we don't know what the user wants and clearly neither does the developer and the developer must go back to the users to find out. Making a choice as a guess as to how you think it should be (and in this case we don't even have a clue as to why he is doing this to give a hint of what would be the best behavior) is a poor programming technique. Requirements questions are the domain of the users not the developers.

Comment: @HLGEM: Well I can say I disagree with you too. Funny that everybody compares this to my answer. Is this a contest of some sort I'm not aware of? I think it's actually a good practice to advertise something and deliver what's advertised. If I say "flying car", you expect a car that flies. If I say isTransposed, you expect something that checks if it's transposed. There's no abstraction involved. You're just making a simple problem a lot more complicated than it should be.

Comment: @netcoder Is transposed doesn't have one immutable meaning to users. And you don;t know inthis case if the function name is truthfully indicative of what they wanted. If he was sure of th emeaning (I can see it either way myself), he would not have asked the question. He didn't ask how to determine if it was transposed but whether it was.  You have to ask what they mean. Developers who have questions about what is meant need to ask the users not other developers. That is the point of this answer and why your answer is significantly wrong. You are sending him down the wrong path.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm concerned, if your function is called `isTransposed`, then checking the values of `11/11` and `11/11` should yield `true`.

The definition of *transpose* is:

> Cause (two or more things) to change places with each other.<sup>[[1]](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3atranspose)</sup>

...it doesn't have anything to do with input and output being identical.

Think of it as:

```
/**
 * Check whether date2 is the same as date1 with the month and day
 * transposed.
 */
boolean isTransposed(Date date1, Date date2);
```

However, having:

```
/**
 * Determine whether or not the month and day of date1 have been
 * transposed in date2.
 */
boolean hasBeenTransposed(Date date1, Date date2);
```

Then it could fail, because it would not have a reasonable way to figure out whether or not they *really were* successfully transposed.

**Update**:
After receiving numerous comments about how *"I can only guess what the expected result would be"*, let me clear it all up once and for all.

The question is:

> When checking for transposed day and month values between two Dates - should comparing 11/11/2000 and 11/11/2000 return true or false?

And the function is:

```
boolean isTransposed();
```

Now, this function contains two words: *is* and *transposed*. We all know what *is* refers to: *to be*. Not *may be*: **to be**. You can find the definition for *tranposed* above.

There is no context whatsoever, and none of these two words are up to interpretation: they each have their own clear definition.

The question is not *"Is this function name appropriate?"* or *"What should this function check for?"*. If one thinks otherwise, then he is the one guessing.

Comment: But if they're identical, how would you *know* that they were really transposed?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: You don't want to know if they *were* transposed, you want to know if you transpose `date1` as described in the question, will *become* `date2`? And the answer in this case is yes. Whether or not you need to change the input to make it output is irrelevant. If the function signature was `Date tranpose(Date input);`, it would be different, because the function wouldn't have any effect, and failing in this case could be appropriate.

Comment: Ah, the difference between "A and B were transposed (and we know it for certain)" and "A and B might have been transposed (but we don't know for sure)".

Comment: @netcoder: I suggest that you have no way of knowing that.  Either interpretation is equally valid.  The only reasonable solution is to define what the actual requirement is in a way that covers the case we're considering.  Resolving that, given just the name `isTransposed`, is not possible.  Once it's been defined, implementing it is trivial.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Semantically, **is** (as in `isTransposed`) defines that if you transpose the input and it gives the output (whether they're the same or not is irrelevant in semantics), then it's true.

Comment: @netcoder: Maybe. Or maybe the name the OP used isn't the best one.  The *only* proper approach is to find out which functionality is more useful, and implement that.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I can't say I disagree with you. This question was direct and precise though, so I'm not going to second guess the OP there.